# Sequelize Foreach loop sends response before updating data

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, foreach, sequelize.js

I'm trying to fetch all content and media from a post and then append to a new post to send to the response for easy access of data. The problem is that whenever I run the call the response is sent before the content and media is fetched.

```
module.exports.getPosts = function(req,res){
var resultPosts = [];
Post.findAll({where:{UserUsername:req.headers.x_username}}).then(function(posts){
    posts.forEach(function(post){
        Db.getContent(post.id,function(foundContent){
            Db.getMedia(post.id,function(foundMedia){
                console.log('creating new post');
                var newPost = {
                    id:post.id,
                    time:post.time,
                    username:post.UserUsername,
                    content: foundContent,
                    media:foundMedia
                };
                resultPosts.push(newPost);
            });
        });
    });//foreach
    console.log('sending');
    res.send({posts:resultPosts});
});//end query
```

};

Comment: This is not correct.  It's close, but will fail.

Answer (score 0):

Remember your working with asynchronous code, as you said, you're calling res.send before the getMedia callback has finished working. Move res.send to that callback, to make sure its called after you have finished pushing to the resultPosts array

```
module.exports.getPosts = function(req,res){
var resultPosts = [];
Post.findAll({where:{UserUsername:req.headers.x_username}}).then(function(posts){
    posts.forEach(function(post){
        Db.getContent(post.id,function(foundContent){
            Db.getMedia(post.id,function(foundMedia){
                console.log('creating new post');
                var newPost = {
                    id:post.id,
                    time:post.time,
                    username:post.UserUsername,
                    content: foundContent,
                    media:foundMedia
                };
                resultPosts.push(newPost);
                console.log('sending');
                res.send({posts:resultPosts});
            });
        });
    });//foreach

});//end query
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to make the entire function async.  In this particular case you must forEach through all the results first, then output to res.  You could use async.forEach() method to solve this: https://codeburst.io/javascript-async-await-with-foreach-b6ba62bbf404

I would do a simply async recursive function with iterators, keeping it all native without any need for extra libraries.

```
var resultPosts = []
        Post.findAll({where:{UserUsername:req.headers.x_username}}).then(function(posts) 
        {
                getPost(posts[Symbol.iterator]())
                function getPost(iter) {
                        var cursor = iter.next()
                        if(cursor.done)
                           return res.send({posts:resultPosts})
                  Db.getContent(post.id,function(foundContent){
                     Db.getMedia(post.id,function(foundMedia){
                         var post = cursor.value
                        resultPosts.push({
                          id:post.id,
                          time:post.time,
                           username:post.UserUsername,
                             content: foundContent,
                          media:foundMedia
                         })
                  getPost(iter)
               }
           })
         })
```